# Destroy an array of objects along with their associates in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3.2. I have heard that `delete` is faster than `destroy`, and that `delete` won't make callbacks, but am not sure how to use `delete`. I have the following as a Rake task:

```
# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
end

# review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
end

# shop.rake
desc "Delete shops"
task :destroy_shops => :environment do
  Shop.find_by_sql("SELECT id FROM shops WHERE shop_status = 0").destroy_all
end
```

Of course this won't work because `destroy_all` doesn't run on an array of objects. What is the best approach to destroy `shops` quickly and its associates? Note that `review` is just one of the many associates to `shop`.

Also note that I my `SQL` is simplified. I have more complicated query that joins table to retrieve unwanted `shops`. I just simplified it for this question.

Comment: http://nick.recoil.org/2006/08/searching-for-a-rails-delete_by_sql-method/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Shop.find_by_sql(...).map(&:destroy)
```

It should have exactly the same behavior as the destroy_all has: "[Destroys the records matching conditions by instantiating each record and calling its destroy method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class)"